# Railsの中間テーブルの命名規則について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

よくある中間テーブルは、categories <-> category_products <-> products のような感じで、アルファベット順で、category_productsのような中間テーブルを作成すると思います。

今回、お尋ねしたいのが、recipe <-> recipe_statuses <-> users のような感じで、ステータスを主に扱う中間テーブルを持ちたい場合、recipe_statusesのような命名でもいいのでしょうか？それともrecipe_usersのような命名の方がいいのでしょうか？

```
recipe_statuses:
  recipe_id
  user_id
  status (enum: approved, declined)
```

Comment: RecipeとUserの関係がn:nになっている理由が気になります。その理由がわかるとrecipe_status よりももっと適切な命名が出てくるかもしれません。たとえば、クックパッドのような料理サイトを想像すると、Recipe belongs_to user、User has_many recipes のような1:nのモデル構成が最初に思い浮かびます。また、statusはRecipeの属性（recipe.status）として管理できそうなので中間テーブルはいらない気がしました。

Answer (score 4):

Rails 1〜2の頃は、多対多の関連に has_and_belongs_to_many が使用されていました。
has_and_belongs_to_manyを使用する場合、"categories_products"のような命名が推奨されていたため、古い記事などではまだこの表記が残っています。

現在では has_and_belongs_to_many は非推奨とされ、has_many :throughに置き換わったため、
モデル名を単純に結合して"categories_products"のようにするのではなく、極力テーブル名自体に意味を持たせる形に変わりました。

Answer (score 0):

recipe_statusesのような命名で良いのではないでしょうか。

モデル名2つをアルファベット順でくっつける、みたいな慣習は特にないと思います。
例えばRailsガイドでも以下のような例が挙げられています。

physicians <-> appointments <-> patients

参考
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association